# SQL You can't specify target table

Tags: mysql, sql

*all structure tables in **[sqlfile:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55130)***

```
UPDATE MenuPosition 
         SET Position = (SELECT Position FROM MenuPosition WHERE MenuId ='2') 
WHERE MenuId ='1'
```

When we use query we get error:

```
You can't specify target table 'MenuPosition' for update in FROM clause
```

Tell me please where my error nd how will be right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup.  That's a limitation in MySQL.  Instead, use `join`:

```
UPDATE MenuPosition mp cross join
       (SELECT Position FROM MenuPosition WHERE MenuId ='2'
       ) mp2
    SET mp.Position = mp2.Position 
    WHERE MenuId = '1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that

```
UPDATE MenuPosition as tbl1
JOIN MenuPosition as tbl2 on 
    tbl1.MenuId = '1'
    AND tbl2.MenuId = '2'
SET tbl1.Position = tbl2.Position
```

Comment: Are you sure it was the same error? I tested this code before submitting the answer and it works. Maybe it is related to the MySQL version. I'm using 5.5.29.